# Why are linear forms called "forms"?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, linear-algebra, algebra

My question is about linear forms, quadratic forms, n-linear forms, differential forms and so on. The first term of these names seem clear to me, but I cannot make a link between these mathematical objects and the usual meanings of the word "form".
I was unable to find an answer on the Internet. Knowing the first occurence of this use of "form" in mathematics would probably help.

Comment: The terminology goes back to Gauss's *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, where he writes (in Latin):"*In this section we shall treat in particular functions in two unknowns $x, y$ of the form $axx + 2bxy + cyy$ where $a, b, c$ are given integers. We will call these functions forms of the second degree or simply forms.*" For this and similar questions see Jeff Miller's website [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](https://jeff560.tripod.com/q.html).

Comment: [From Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forma#Latin) with the meaning of shape, pattern. Today, we would say *expressions*.